# Moving frames for geometric abstract surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

After playing for few time with the method of moving frames for surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, I decided to try to apply it to study geometric surfaces (topological surfaces with an inner product). I have no trouble in doing calculations: with the first fundamental form I can recover $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$, then $dA$, then $\omega_{12}$, $K$... but I have a theoretical problem. Following the method, I have $\{{e}_1, e_2\}$ ON positive basis for $T_pS$ for every p in S and I want to write $dP, de_1, de_2$ with respect of this basis. I would write

$dP = \omega_1e_1 + \omega_2e_2\\ de_1 = \omega_{12}e_2 *\\ de_2 = -\omega_{12}e_1 *$

But then, if I take the integrability condition (exterior derivative) I get

$d\omega_1 = \omega_{12}\wedge\omega_2 \\ d\omega_2 = -\omega_{12}\wedge\omega_1 \\ d\omega_{12} = 0$

Clearly, the last equation is not correct. So I suspect that the (*) equations are not correct too. I think that the problem is that $e_i$ changes also outside the tangent plane (as in $\mathbb{R}^3$). So I tried to get more formal writing where the functions lives:

$P :S \to S \\ 
\ \ \ \ \ \  p \to p
 \\ e_i: S \to TS \\
\ \ \ \ \ \  p \to e_i(p) \in T_pS$

and also their derivatives **

$(dP)_p : T_pS \to T_pS \\
(de_i)_p: T_pS \to T_{e_i(p)}TS$

So I think that is correct to express $(dP)_p$ in terms of $e_i(p)$, because $(dP)_p$ lives in $T_pS$. Instead $(de_i)_p$ lives in a 4-dimensional space, $T_{e_i(p)}TS$, where, I suppose, $e_1$ and $e_2$ induce only half of the base. Is this true?

I'm really confused and I don't know how to google these things.

Thanks in advance

** I don't anything about TS, the tangent bundle, other than that is the union of the tangent planes and it is a 2n dimensional manifold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you did stuff in $\Bbb R^3$, you could think of differentiating vector-valued functions to make sense of equations like $de_1 = \omega_{12}e_2 + \omega_{13}e_3$. Now, you cannot really write $de_1$, as $e_1$ is a vector bundle valued function. So this is really the covariant derivative $\nabla e_1 = \omega_{12} e_2$. But one usually skips this and just defines $\omega_{12}$ uniquely, as you suggested, by the two equations $d\omega_1 = \omega_{12}\wedge\omega_2$ and $d\omega_2 = -\omega_{12}\wedge\omega_1$. [Note that if $\omega_{12} = P\omega_1+Q\omega_2$, then the first equation determines $P$ and the second determines $Q$.] Now, the next structure equation becomes $d\omega_{12} = \Omega_{12} = -K\omega_1\wedge\omega_2$ [not $0$].

Let me suggest a [nice new book](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-178/) on moving frames. Perhaps you can find it in your library. For more advanced things, the master of 20th century moving frames, S.S. Chern, wrote [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BY9TI7W).

I'll be glad to help within reason, too. :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! You are the only one who answer my questions. I got really fascinated by the moving frames method, it gave me a really big insight in surface theory.   I know that $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ determine completely $\omega_{12}$ : is what I have done one thousand times working in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and also for some abstract surface, like flat torus, Klein bottle, projective plane...

Comment: The approach you mentioned is the same of Elementary differential geometry of O'Neill: we know that in $\mathbb{R}^3$  works in a way, so we define it the same way for abstract surface. For me, it is not a completely satisfactory approach, because it is not in spirit of moving frames method, where you differentiate and _obtain_ $\omega_{12}$. I know that for pratical purposes, you get the same thing, but.. it is artificial! Could you try to explain me, maybe with an example, why I cannot write $de_1$ in an abstract surface? Thank you also for the references.

Comment: I answer your questions because I'm one of a large handful of geometers who have used moving frames in research and teaching. ... You can define $df$ for any vector-space valued function $f$. (You can easily write down the definition, choosing a basis and writing it out component by component, and you can check it's well-defined independent of basis.) But you're wanting to take the exterior derivative of a vector-*bundle* valued function $e_1$. Tell me how you'd define such a thing. If you try to do the analogous thing, you'll fail at checking well-definedness since there's no global basis.

Comment: I'm just playing and trying, so please forgive me if I say things that don't make sense. My idea was: $TS = \{(p, v) | p \in S, v \in T_pS\} = \{(p(u, v), \lambda_1e_1 + \lambda_2e_2) | (u, v) \in D, \lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \mathbb{R}\}$ So maybe a basis for $T_{e_i(p)}TS$ could be $({\partial P \over \partial u}, 0) ({\partial P \over \partial v}, 0), (0, {\partial P \over \partial \lambda_1} = e_1) (0, {\partial P \over \partial \lambda_2} = e_2)$ and so I could express $de_1$ respect this basis.. that's totally wrong?

Comment: The problem is that $e_1,e_2$ cannot be chosen constant locally. In fact, only in the case that the surface is flat can you find a frame with $\nabla e_1=\nabla e_2 = 0$. (BTW, that's an excellent moving frames exercise for you. Prove that $K=0$ iff locally your surface is isometric to $\Bbb R^2$.) Note that your basis for $T_qTS$ fails to be valid even for a sphere in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: I wrote a wrong thing (at least, wrong for what I mean). For $S^2$ we have $P = (cosu cosv, cosusinv, sinu), e_1 = (-sinucosv, -sinusinv, cosu), e_2 = (-sinv, cosv, 0)$. I think then that $TS^2 = \{(cosucosv, cosusinv, sinu, -\lambda sinucosv - \mu sinv, -\lambda sinusinv + \mu cosv, \lambda cosu)\}$ and then as basis for $T_pTS^2$ I get $(-sinucosv, -sinusinv, cosu, -\lambda cosucosv, -\lambda cosusinv, -\lambda sinu), (-cosusinv, cosucosv, 0, ...), (0, 0, 0, e_1), (0, 0, 0, e_2)$. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Sorry if I insist, but I cannot understand why I can calculate $d\omega_1$ and not $de_1$..

Comment: Where do the values live? $\omega_1(v)\in\Bbb R$ for any tangent vector $v$ at $p$. $e_1\in T_pS$, and this abstract vector space varies as $p$ varies. You still haven't told me how to define the derivative of that. To reiterate, we know how to differentiate *functions* or *differential forms* with values in a *fixed* vector space. We do *not* know how to differentiate these things when the values are in a space that's moving around abstractly.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I'm still confused. I mean: you say that $e_i$ has values in a vector space that varies, but you really cannot write $e_i : S \mapsto T_pS$, because, as you say, $T_pS$ varies. I mean: this is not the correct codomain.  Working in $\mathbb{R}^3$ we have that $T_pS \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and so we can write $e_i : S \mapsto \mathbb{R}^3$ and all works fine. Now, for an abstract surface I think we can do the same, because $T_pS \subset TS$ and $TS$ is fixed. Now we have $e_i : S \mapsto TS$, a map between two manifolds, and we can differentiate it... or not?